# Конвертирование между форматами. Java

Tags: java, конвертация

Хочу научится конвертировать mp4 в mp3 и тому подобное на Java. Подскажите в какую сторону начинать копать. 
Очень рад буду увидеть примеры кода и книжки где есть толкование на эту тематику.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал для начала ознакомится с [ffmpeg](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть простая в использовании Java-библиотека [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php). Она основана на ffmpeg и подходит для конвертирования между различными аудио/видео форматами.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите написать такой код, то Вам лучше всего будет использовать библитоку написаную на С. А именно [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), как написали Вам в комментариях. А также стоит научится понимать и работать с JNI. 
Для первого знакомаства рекомендую почитать статью ["Как подружить Java и C++"](https://habrahabr.ru/post/49660/).